# Dynamic qtip not loading jquery sparkline graph

Tags: jquery

I have values stored in JQuery.data method and are successfully placing a div with a sparkline graph (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) next to the input. I want to then place those sparkline graphs in the tip for the input. The tip appears and seems to resize to the size of the graphs but the tip is empty, nothing appears.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob

**Code Updated**

I added  $.sparkline_display_visible() and the graph now partially appears.  The bottom half of the sparkline now appears.  I have tried to add padding or margin to the div but only the bottom of the half of the graph appears?

$("input").each(function() {

var theinput = $(this);
var newValue = $(theinput).data( "Data" )

if ( $(newValue).length ) { 
   var theclass = $(theinput).attr('class');
    //alert(theclass + '=' + newValue.theValue );

theclass = 'rob_' + theclass

var theplaceholder = $(theinput).after('' + newValue.theValue + '');
   var myvalues = [newValue.theValue,thetotal];
   $('.' + theclass ).sparkline(myvalues, {type: 'pie', offset: '+90' }).attr('title', newValue.theValue + ' of ' + thetotal );

```
$(theplaceholder).qtip({    
prerender: true,                                
content: $('.' + theclass),
show: { ready: true },
style: { name: 'cream', tip: true, padding: '10' }              
});
$.sparkline_display_visible()
```

$('canvas,span').css('overflow','visible');

$('[class^=qtip]').css('overflow','visible');

}

});

**Update**
From within Firebug I found that the canvas for the sparkline graph is set to overflow: hidden which is a known bug with FireFox 3.6x.

I updated the code above and it works perfectly in Internet Explorer (amazing LOL).  Is there any fix for FireFox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the $.sparkline_display_visible() method when the qtip is made visible.. Try:

```
$('.' + theoriginalclass ).qtip({
   prerender: true,
   content: $('.' + theclass).html(),
   show: { ready: true },
   style: { name: 'cream', tip: true},
   onShow: function() { $.sparkline_display_visible(); }
});
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, tried your suggestion and it didn't work.  I even added a setTimeout before attaching the qtip with the sparkline to the class and it sill didn't work.  Hmmm.

Comment: Well the last person to email me about using qtip wasn't using prerender: true.  - Instead they had an onRender: function() { $(...).sparkline(); } call in there in addition to the onShow() display visible stuff that did the trick.  Don't know if that helps or not.